# Rails 3 form_for is set to remote: true but the request is still submitted as HTML

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form_tag where I have remote set to true, however the form is still submitted as HTML

Here is what I got:

```html
    <%= form_tag('/permissions/update_resource', remote: true, method: :post) do %>
    
    <!-- Form goes here -->
    
<% end %>
```

This in return generates HTML looking like this:

```html
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/permissions/update_resource" data-remote="true" method="post">
<!-- form goes here -->
</form>
```

The problem is that when form is submitted, the request comes through in HTML format. Any idea what could be wrong here? I am totally at loss.

I got simple AJAX request working one same page, so I am pretty sure my Rail app is configured correctly...

Comment: are you sure you are having the `jquery-data-remote` npm package installed? its not default jquery

Comment: I have this jquery lib: 
$ dpkg --list | grep -i jquery
ii  libjs-jquery                                    1.11.3+dfsg-4                              all         JavaScript library for dynamic web applications

I also have jquery-rails gem installed: 
$ gem list | grep -i jquery
jquery-rails (3.1.4)

I am able to create a link and have it submitted as XHR so I don't think system packages are to blame

Answer (score 1):

So apparently my problem was with how I was submitting the form. I had this in my code inside select_tag:

```js
onchange: "this.form.submit();"
```

somehow this made the form submit as html. I changed this line to:

```html
onchange: "$('#update_resource_#{resource.id}').submit();"
```

and bang! - the form submits as js
I still don't know why :-(
Is someone has and explanation, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to install the **`jquery-rails`-gem** and to include both **`jquery`** and **`jquery_ujs`** in your js-manifest-file (in `assets/javascripts/application.js`) - e.g. like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

For more details (incl alternate installation instructions via npm) check out **[jquery-ujs - Ruby on Rails unobtrusive scripting adapter for jQuery](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)**